# How to structure the code of a game?

Tags: software-engineering, design-patterns

I come from a web development background and want to learn game programming. To bridge the gap, I plan on creating a simple one-on-one fighting game in JavaScript. There’s two fighters on a stage, and the fighters can kick and punch until one’s health is depleted.

I get I would need a game loop that has hit detection and also listens for user input (keyboard), but what I *don’t* get is how to link the different components of a game together. I think these would be called “activities”.

For example, what is the usual programming pattern used to go from a character select screen to the actual match? Or a pause menu? Or when a match ends to replay or go back to the character selection screen? I have a good idea of how to program these separate activities, but linking them together into one, flowing game is where I get lost.

Comment: Hey Martin. These types of questions are a bit too broad for the site. Check out state machines and try some game tutorials. You'll find the basic structures you can expand upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice series of articles called "How we Built an iOS game on PC" on gamedev. It's about what you might think, but also charts the development of their game from absolute start to finish.

They reference a blog, and specifically two entries, one of which is about the idea of "scenes". A scene is essentially a class that encapsulates the data and game loop relating to a single part of the game, like the character select screen. Or more straightforwardly, in a game with 'levels', there could be a scene for each level. Each class implements the same interface, Load, Unload, Update etc. Then you have a class that manages the current scene, i.e. calling Update once a frame, and switches to a new scene, calling the appropriate methods.

One way to think about the pause menu is as just another element of your GUI. If you manage your GUI and scene separately, you can stop updating the scene (while continuing to draw it if required) and update and draw the menu. The second blog entry referenced is about the "GUI Stack", which I thought was a really elegant way to handle GUI elements, updating, drawing, layering etc.

I quite like both of those concepts, though they may not be appropriate for what you're doing.

The scene concept is used in the Unity engine, and it has its own slightly modified version of JavaScript for a scripting language as well. Could be a starting point, if you want to get a feel for what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on which programming language you are using for the game you are creating ... but from what you have said you are using javascript and you want to know how to link parts i suggest separating things like char selection,replay in files and then called them up in the main game file which should be heavily separated with comment lines like (make something like start regions and end regions) like this :

```
Main Game File:
//********************************
//some other region ....
code
code
code

//******************************
// start region CharSelection Menu

  start.gamemenu();
  other code...


//endregion
```

At least that what i would do for my own games ...There are other methods and probably if you find some source codes of games written in javascript it will help you find which method would suit you better...